# Закрепление блока с контентом и его скролл

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
https://codepen.io/Lareta/pen/XWRQeBy
```

Большая просьба помочь вот с таким моментом, не знаю как это можно реализовать, всё уже перепробовал, знаний не хватает:

```
<body>
    <div class="text">
    <h1>Ребята, кто подскажет</h1>
        <p>Во время скролла страницы как сделать так, что бы когда блок с красными квадратами встал в центре, то дальнейшее прокручивание колесика мыши скроллило не страницу, а красные квадраты </p>
    </p>
            А после того, как контент прокрутится до конца, продолжился скролл страницы.
            Ну и так же в обратном порядке, когда скролл сраницы снизу вверх, доходим до секции с квадратами, дальнейший скролл прокручивает их сверху вниз, а потом только продолжается скролл страницы.
        </p>
    <p> Благодарна за любую наводку или подсказку. А может есть готовый плагин или скрипт! </p>
    </div>
<div id="scroll-section">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text">
        <p>Во время скролла страницы как сделать так, что бы когда блок с красными квадратами встал в центре, то дальнейшее прокручивание колесика мыши скроллило не страницу, а красные квадраты </p>
    </p>
            А после того, как контент прокрутится до конца, продолжился скролл страницы.
            Ну и так же в обратном порядке, когда скролл сраницы снизу вверх, доходим до секции с квадратами, дальнейший скролл прокручивает их сверху вниз, а потом только продолжается скролл страницы.
        </p>
    <p> Благодарна за любую наводку или подсказку. А может есть готовый плагин или скрипт! </p>
    </div>
      
    </body>
```

Основная идея, чтобы когда доскраливали до нужного блока он вставал по центру и мы не могли скроллить до тех пор, пока не прокрутим весь контент.

Просьба ещё помочь с вариантом, где таких блоков, как в примере будет несколько.

Comment: возможно вам стоит поиграться с `position: stiky`. применяется он не к блоку с контентом, а к тому блоку который должен оставаться на месте при скроле контента. либо с `overflow: scroll`. он уже для блока с контентом. с первым вариантом могут быть проблемки, особенно если надо несколько, а вот второй проще пареной репы(оба варианта - css свойства). p.s. `перепробоваЛ`, `благодарНА` :3

Comment: Такое же задание девушка выкладывала, я его в пример просто привёл, чтобы тоже самое не писать)
Вот в том то и дело, пытался и так и так с position: sticky, но ничего не вышло, давал блоку, в котором есть контент, высоту в несколько экранов, вроде и выходило примерно то, что нужно, а вот скролл оставался независимым.